# How to add a TextView to LinearLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add `TextViews` to my xml-defined layout in code.
I have a xml-sheet, where a lot of `Views` are defined. But I have to add some views in code, so a create a `LinearLayout` in the xml-sheet:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

And in this layout, I like to add my `TextView`:

```
    View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);
    //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.info);


    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
    valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
    valueTV.setId(5);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
```

But I only get the following error message:

```
: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
```

How can I do it?

Thanks for you help.
Martin

Comment: Which line is that exception for? It must be from the LinearLayout cast, are you sure the linearLayout variable is a LinearLayout and not a TextView? Also you shouldn't be specifying the Id since you can't guarantee it will be unique.

Comment: You are right, linearLayout is a TextView, but why?
I have defined it in the xml-file as a LinearLayout ...

Comment: Make sure you are really operating on the xml shown above. Is `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_layout);` really loading the right xml? Do you have other xml layouts where you use `android:id="@+id/info"` which happen to be a TextView?

Comment: Is this issue resolved? Kindly accept as answer or post one.

Answer (score 111):

try using

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.info);
...
linearLayout.addView(valueTV);
```

also make sure that the layout params you're creating are LinearLayout.LayoutParams...

Comment: there is again an exception, because findViewById returns an TextView. But why? I fetch it with the LinearLayout id....

what do you mean with:
also make sure that the layout params you're creating are LinearLayout.LayoutParams...  ???

Comment: Why would that change anything? All it does is cast sooner rather than later, which should have the same effect.

Answer (score 77):

Hey i have checked your code, there is no serious error in your code. this is complete code:

main.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

this is Stackoverflow.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Stackoverflow extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);
        //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.info);

        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
        valueTV.setId(5);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
    }
}
```

copy this code, and run it. it is completely error free.
take care...

Comment: What if I wanted to have the following TextView: `<TextView
              android:id="@+id/tvDInfo3"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:text="Release Date"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:padding="@dimen/dyk_text_pad"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="@dimen/info_text_size"
              android:layout_weight="1" />`

Comment: +1. This answer is much better than @Ben's as it contains an example of LayoutParams and how the rest of the properties of the `TextView` is initialised. This should be marked as an answer.

Comment: How to do it inside button click `onClick(View v)`

Answer (score 23):

You can add a `TextView` to your linear layout programmatically like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
TextView txt1 = new TextView(MyClass.this);
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
linearLayout.addView(txt1);
```

Comment: What is MyClass.this? I'm new to Android development; am I supposed to substitute the name of my fragment class in for "MyClass"?

Comment: MyClass.this is a context and a text view takes in a context

Comment: Just for clarification: `MyClass.this`, in most cases, is the same as `this`. You need to specify, however, the name of the class, if you are in a nested class and want to access the instance of the "outer" class, which is very common when defining callbacks for the events in android.

Comment: I guess some android developers got used to putting the name of the class where it's needed and started putting it everywhere. Also, `MyClass.this` is an instance of `MyClass`, and it will only be a context if MyClass implements Context (e.g. extends Activity)

Answer (score 23):

```
for(int j=0;j<30;j++) {
    LinearLayout childLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childLayout.setLayoutParams(linearParams);

    TextView mType = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    TextView mValue = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

    mType.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    mValue.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

    mType.setTextSize(17);
    mType.setPadding(5, 3, 0, 3);
    mType.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    mType.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER);

    mValue.setTextSize(16);
    mValue.setPadding(5, 3, 0, 3);
    mValue.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
    mValue.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER);

    mType.setText("111");
    mValue.setText("111");

    childLayout.addView(mValue, 0);
    childLayout.addView(mType, 0);

    linear.addView(childLayout);
}
```

Comment: has to define,  linear.addView(childLayout);,  linear as Linear Layout at first

Answer (score 12):

In **Kotlin** you can add Textview as follows.

```
 val textView = TextView(activity).apply {
            layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ).apply {
                setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0)
                setPadding(10, 10, 0, 10)
            }
            text = "SOME TEXT"
            setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.colorPrimary))
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
            textSize = 16.0f
            typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD)
        }
 linearLayoutContainer.addView(textView)
```

Answer (score 11):

You should use something similar to this for adding TextView to LinearLayout dynamically:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.infoLayout);

TextView valueTV = new TextView(context);
valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
valueTV.setId(Integer.parseInt("5"));
valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

linearLayout.addView(valueTV);
```

getActivity() is used for inside Fragments, you can use context or anything similar per each instance you are inside.

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the layout via it's layout resource, not an id resource which is not guaranteed unique.  The resource reference should look like R.layout.my_cool_layout where your above XML layout is stored in res/layout/my_cool_layout.xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams ;
layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's where the exception occurs

```
((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
```

`addView` method takes in a parameter of type **`View`**, not **`TextView`**. Therefore,   typecast  the valueTv object into a View object, explicitly.

Therefore, the corrected code would be :

```
((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView((TextView)valueTV);
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes, I have. And it works perfectly! Have you tried it?