# Parsed XML to Layout in Android?

Tags: xml, android-layout

I am working on an application in Android in which I need to design the layout of the application dynamically. I have to get the details of the layout from the database via XML and show the parse results on the screen as per the requirement. For example, XML will have the number of TextView and Buttons which will be included in the UI.

Can someone please suggest me the possible approach to implement this in Android SDK?

Thanks in Advance,
Aagrah

Comment: Anyone can please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the layout on the fly in Android. Create a Linear/RelativeLayout, then add TextViews and Buttons programatically into it.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7445160/72746) on how to add item programatically.