# Can an activity change its look

Tags: android

I have an activity and a layout having nine ImageButtons and activities(think all of these  as sub apps) attached to it, I have some more additional ImageButtons and activities attached to those buttons(more sub apps), the user should be able to choose only nine activities(sub apps) for the main layout, is this possible.

If we want that activity choose the sub app else delete any of the activity(sub app) from the main screen.

For example

Like what we do on our windows desktop, whatever we want we keep as shortcut we keep it as icon and if we dont need we replace it or delete the icon, can same be reproduced in android.

Any help or pointers would be helpful.

thanks.

Comment: able to choose only nine activities for the main layout,?? There are some confusion in this point. Give more light into it.

Comment: @PareshMayani I have many activities around 15 and each activity has an ImageButton, and clicking on ImageButton will take to its activity. But the main screen can only show nine ImageButtons, can the user delete and replace these some of the ImageButtons and activities added with it. Like what we do on our windows desktop, whatever we want we keep it as icon and if we dont need we replace it or delete the icon, can same be reproduced in android.

Comment: You can set each icon's visiblity.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, but I am having a lot of trouble. Can you try re-writing it, or add more detail.

Comment: @EGHDK I have many activities but can only show nine in a screen, what I want is can a user customise what all activities he wants on his main screen, its like he gets an dropdown box selects those activities and those activities shows up on the main screen. This is the reason I have given example of windows desktop, add icons for what you want activity call it on your main screen and delete others which you dont require. can this be done in android. hope you understood. thanks.

Comment: I guess you can store what the user selected in Sqlite or something. Then onCreate, you retrieve those ImageButtons and add them programmatically. Just to give you an idea though.

Comment: @userIsAMonkey how do you write a layout for this activity. thanks.

Comment: Get an idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically