# can i add Textview programmatically to appwidget without defining it in the xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I did alot of research to do the following:
I want to add a text view by code in the `AppWidgetProvider` class , but i couldnt do that because the `addView` method of `RemoteViews` require an id of the view that is already defined in the xml layout.

And i want to add textview's depending on the size of the widget so can i do that ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Yes you can check this [Link][1] its may help you.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7445160/1412308

or

Comment: @RajeshRajaram thats in an activity , i want to do that in AppWidgetProvider , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7445160/1412308) its may help you.

or

```
TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
valueTV.setId(5);
valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```