# Sending data to other activity and display some additional TextViews

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android application in which i send data from one activity to another. I can do that part easily but the problem is i want to display some additional TextViews as well. So when i display the sent data using `setContentView` i can see only the sent data. I cannot see the additional TextViews. I want both of them to be displayed simultaneously.

I searched and tried hard to find a solution without any luck.I am attaching the code for reference.Thanks!

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_information);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(CropsListActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textViewci= new TextView(this);
    textViewci.setText(message);
    TextView textView1= new TextView(this);
    TextView textView2= new TextView(this);
    textView1.setText("Major Districts");
    textView2.setText("Suitable Soil");
```

When i use this code,i am unable to see anything and the activity remains blank.Actually i am using a `TableLayout` here so that i can display data in form of tables

Comment: I have got the answer.Thanks everyone who tried to answer my question.Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the answer by myself.It's fairly easy and there is no need here to use views in the parent layout.I modified the textViews in my xml file and got their values using `findViewById`.I am attaching the updated code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_information);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(CropsListActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewci);
    textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewmd);
    textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewso);
    textView.setText(message);
    textView1.setText("Major Districts");
    textView2.setText("Suitable Soil");
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SHRUTIB.TTF");
    textView.setTypeface(tf);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add text view on your layout.

```
View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);
//LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.info);


TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
valueTV.setId(5);
valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
```

Comment: Sorry,i didn't got your answer. Would you please be descriptive?

Comment: u have to add ur text view in ur layout Akash

Comment: show link for better understand <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically>

Comment: in above example it take view but u can also try linear layout LinearLayout linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the text view in the parentview. For example, if you have used the text view in the linear layout then add the text view in the linear layout and then use the addview(linearlayout).

Below is the example

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("A");
tv1.setId(23);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setText("B");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv1.getId());

layout.addView(tv1);       
layout.addView(tv2, lp);
```

Comment: i tried doing this,but there is no change in my output,its still blank!

Answer (score 1):

are you getting any error messages? if yes then please post them here. and the others are right.you need to add yours views to the parent layout.

Comment: do you want to display the text within the TextViews?

Comment: Yeah, that was my question.

Comment: you can add the TextViews to your xml layout file. access them within your activity using the findViewById() method, and then display text in them.
e.g,

`TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); //textView1 is declared in the layout xml file
textView1.setText("some text");`

Comment: Haha,i had already answered my question which is the same as your comment before you posted it.Thanks for the help!

Comment: not a problem.good to see that you found a solution. is there any particular need to use these two statements? 
`tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SHRUTIB.TTF");
    textView.setTypeface(tf);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23955/discussion-between-akash-shah-and-poonam-anthony)

Answer (score 1):

```
I have just make a test program for you. first class code

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondClass.class);
        intent.putExtra("firstValue", "1");
        intent.putExtra("secondValue", "2");
        startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

Second class code :

setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_information);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message1 = intent.getStringExtra("firstValue");
        String message2 = intent.getStringExtra("secondValue");

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        TextView textView1= new TextView(this);
        TextView textView2= new TextView(this);

        TextView textViewci= new TextView(this);
        textViewci.setText(message1+""+message2);
        Log.e("intent value is", ""+message1+""+message2);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView1.getId());


        textView1.setText("Major Districts");
        textView2.setText("Suitable Soil");

        layout.addView(textView1);
        layout.addView(textView2);
        addContentView(layout, lp);

Try and let me know. YOu have to make related layouts for both classes.
Hope this will help
```