# Draw multiple bitmap on a view in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to make a view in which i am having 6-7 different images.
There is no issue in drwaing only one image on a view, but how to draw multiple images on that view.

Here is my code-

```
 Bitmap img1= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.football);
```

And here is my onDraw() method-

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        float hgt=canvas.getHeight();
        float wth=canvas.getWidth();
        System.out.println("hgt and wt is "+hgt+" "+wth);

        if (startMovement) {

            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            startMovement = false;
        }
        CheckCorner(canvas);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

The images are moving from top to bottom, and need to be displayed in a row.

Comment: Are you extending ImageView?

Comment: How and where did you draw your img1 on `Canvas` ??

Comment: This is the source code i am referring to:-  http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-mobile-game-development-part.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can add more that one bitmap to a View.
What you probably want is to add 6-7 ImageViews to a Layout/GroupView:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage1);
ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
iv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage2);
.
.
.
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.addView(iv);
ll.addView(iv2);
```

Also, you can make the linearlayout to layout the views horizontally

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a RelativeLayout or a LinearLayout.

RelativeLayout gives you more flexibility on where to place your views, but requires a little bit more code for the layout parameters (where you want to place the view).  [Check this answer on RelativeLayouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)

If you are going to just put the views in a line (horizontal or vertical), use a LinearLayout instead.  [Check this answer on LinearLayouts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically)