# Stacking 2 Images Android

Tags: android

I have been debugging this issue for the past 6 hours and have simplified my issue to the most simple case (taking out the bulk of my logic). I am trying to stack 2 (chickens) images on top of each other in a view.

I have followed numerous examples including the last answer to :
[Draw multiple bitmap on a view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215766/draw-multiple-bitmap-on-a-view-in-android)

My activity looks like:

```
public class FinalDisplay extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_display);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_final_display);

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
    layout.addView(iv);

    ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
    layout.addView(iv2);

}
```

R.drawable.images is an image of a chicken I took from the Internet and placed in my drawable folder.

```
http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130606165308/animalcrossing/images/4/41/Chicken.jpg
```

My xml page looks like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_final_display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FinalDisplay" >
```

However, only one chicken appears. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: how are you supposed to see the image below?
is there transparency for this image?

Comment: 1 thing you set the image of the same imageview twice

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should have clarified I meant that there should be two images (1 higher up on the page and one on the lower half). Not overlapping.

Comment: A `LinearLayout` isn't suitable for 'stacking' views; it'll place child views either horizontally or vertically next to each other. In stead, try using a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams(int width, int height))

Comment: try this buddy, it may help you....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MH (in comments) is correct.

Replace the LinearLayout with RelativeLayout. The view which is on top is the view which was last added (or declared in XML).

This should work the way you want it to.

Java:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_final_display);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
layout.addView(iv);

ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
layout.addView(iv2);
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_final_display"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FinalDisplay" >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
layout.addView(iv);

ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
iv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
layout.addView(iv2);
```

Try that