# how to add something to layout when application running

Tags: android

I can say I'm new for android application devolepment. I want to give a example to tell you my question.

I'm getting some datas from database I need to create a lot of textviews to put datas into. I think here is some php devoloper, too. When I use php I write something like below.

```
foreach($database_datas as $data)
{
 echo "<li>" + $data["list_item"] + "</li>";
}
```

In android, can we embed? What's the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean add a set of textviews programmatically?
This code shows how to add one textview programmatically to a linear layout. You should be able to put that code in a loop and add multiple textviews.

[Android: Add a textview to linear layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically)

You might also want to check out the doc pages of LinearLayout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) and TextView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: is that the method android programmers always use?

Comment: Yes, to add a textview programmatically.. which is what I think you want to do, do correct me if I'm wrong. You can read the data and start a new activity that would display this data. You can add the textviews to the layout of this activity programmatically using the above code.