# How to PERMANENTLY remove layout items in android java

Tags: java, android, android-view

Fairly inexperienced in java still, so I was wondering (as I haven't really found anything useful online) whether there was a way to permanently delete a textview (or any other layout entry, ratingbar etc.) from an android layout in the onclick function.

I want a user to be able to submit a rating only once in every rateable activity, you see.

I have tried everything I can get.

```
ratingbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Works while you're in the activity, yet when you restart again the ratingbar is back. I've also tried:

```
linearlayout1.removeView( ratingbar );
```

However, this does the same as

```
ratingbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

On reload the ratingbar is back. If anyone can help, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SharedPreferfences`

Comment: create dynamic views show only what you need

Answer (score 0):

Well you rather choose not to create a view,
than deleting a view that's created.

i guess you could create TextView programmatically
and decide if you want to attach it to your layout or not in java code.

See : [Android: Add a textview to linear layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically)