# Displaying two views at once

Tags: java, android

I have a Game class which extends Activity:

```
public class Game extends Activity
...
```

in which I'm setting content view to XML layout, and just after that switching to my GamePanel class like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
```

In GamePanel class I need to update and draw objects on my layout game_layout. But my game_layout isn't showing because of switching to GamePanel.

How do I keep displaying first layout view and switch to class Gamepanel?

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
...
```

Comment: Is the question to put the Gamepanel inside the game layout like a smaller part of it? Or it isn't displaying at all?

Comment: I think you need fragments: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Gamepanel is overlaping whole screen (although I didn't set it any bg or something like that). So it's "displaying" (working). I need it to display over first layout, but transparently, if you know what I mean (just draw views on it over first layout).

Comment: setContentView means you are setting that as your Activity's content view. When you are calling `setContentView(new GamePanel(this))` you are changing the content that you previously set with `setContentView(R.layout.game_layout)`. If you want the `GamePanel` view to overlap the `R.layout.game_layout` not override it, you need to create the GamePanel view and add it to your contentView. Something like `this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).addView(new GamePanel(this))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display **both** views at the same time, try to add dinamically the GamePanel to the main layout view.

You have an example here
[Add view dinamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
```

It overwrites game_layout by GamePanel. To make game_layout is the background you need to setup the GamePanel inside game_layout, i guest it is from game_layout.xml