# Unable to pass set text values dynamically to a text view in android

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater

I am using Layout inflator in my application to suit my requirements. I have  text view, edittext and button in the layout. Here is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayoutid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittextid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayoutid"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="button" />
```

I want to generate 'n' number of text views and pass the values from database. 
I used layout inflator here and below is my code

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutid);
View v = null;


for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {

    v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    lv.addView(v);
}

//  EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittextid);
final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[41];
for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
    d = mydb.getValues();

    myTextViews[i] = tv;
    tv.setText(d.get(i));
    Log.d(tag,"run"+d.get(i));

}
```

Its is generating 'n' number of text views dynamically but the problem is I am not able to display text using 'setText' . Its blank completely . Can anyone please tell me where I am making mistake? I want to pass the dynamic value and not the hard coded one. Any help would be great !! Thanks

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textviewid); is repeatedly called 41 times, without any change! so the TextView Array actually has the same textview!

Comment: No I tried declaring outside the loop too !! @David

Comment: to me, this makes less sense no matter wherever it is. You seem to be misusing loops.

Comment: Remove textviewid from your xml and use lv.addView(myTextViews[i]) after the setText.  [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7445160/1222099)

Comment: lv.addView(v); above this line find textview id and and set your value there and comment below for loop

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying. Could you please post as answer @Pravin

Comment: (myTextViews[i]) is just an array @MachoProgrammer

Comment: I am passing dynamic values via "for loop" I cant pass it before that @Pravin

Comment: r u getting 41 textviews on the UI?

Comment: I tested it by passing hard coded values . And yes, the hard coded values are displaying @NaveenShriyan

Comment: u r telling if u use this code  "tv.setText(d.get(i));" it doesnt work?, and if u use "tv.setText("naveen");"  it will work right?

Comment: give textview text color as black , jus to check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111012/discussion-between-naveen-shriyan-and-anusha).

Answer (score 0):

If you want show list of some data, will be better to use [List view](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). 
Or you can use **RecyclerView**. 
You can find more information about this layouts and how use it on Internet.