# Android : listview with dynamic number of columns

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I want develop an app showing the scores of participants in a challenge. Challenge can have n number of rounds. I want to show the scores in a list  where each row represents the score for a particular round.
The first row would be: score of player 1, score of player 2, score of player 3

The number of players is not fixed. This is the challenge I am facing. I cannot implement using the standard recycler view and adapter with view holder pattern as I cannot statically define the layout for each row.
Please suggest how can I implement this list.

Comment: Why can't you define the layout for each row? Surely you know what it will look like in advance? Also are you referring to `ListView` or `RecyclerView`? You've mentioned both.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create views within logic(java or kotlin instead of xml) inside your recyclerView adapter. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/how-to-add-a-textview-to-linearlayout-in-android) question

Or if you have the time for creating a custom class you can create it and use it in your inflated item of viewHolder / adapter.

Like this one I made for a Tag Layout.
https://gist.github.com/alireza-nezami/ffdebb092f99cf147a9bab4b280f4397